# ColdFusion code to read and filter a .cfm file

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to write a ColdFusion code that does the following?

1. Read a .cfm file
2. Filter the .cfm file for any word that has ".cfm" appended to it.
3. Compare the list of file names found in Step 2 with files in a directory, to find out if there are any files in the directory that are not in the .cfm file.

In step 2 I am trying find .cfm file names in href.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The directory of my test was setup with a reader.cfm and a list.cfm. It was able to find the list.cfm file in the example list file and logged the reader.cfm file as not being present.

Theres probably a better way to get a list of cfm filenames from a file. I'm no guru at regex, but I did test that it worked as desired. It probably won't work if your links have special chars like _ or -. This should give you something to start with though.

```
<cffile action="read"
    file="#expandpath('list.cfm')#"
    variable="fileList">

    <cfset fileResult = rematchNoCase('([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+\.cfm', fileList)>

    <cfdirectory
        directory="#expandPath('.')#"
        action="list"
        filter="*.cfm"
        listInfo="name"
        recurse = "no"
        type="file"
        name="dirList">

    <cfset notInFile = ArrayNew(1)>

    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop query="dirList">
            <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(fileResult)#" index="i">
                <cfif dirList.name eq fileResult[i]>
                    found one! #dirList.name#<br>
                    <cfbreak>
                </cfif>
                <cfif i eq #arrayLen(fileResult)#>
                    Item not found! #dirList.name#<br>
                    <cfset _r = ArrayAppend(notInFile, dirList.name)>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfdump var="#notInFile#">
```

Contents of list.cfm file I used.

```
<a href="someRealLink.cfm">click me to fun</a>
something
other thing
a coldfusion.cfm thing
stuff
things
yar.cfm
blah
Something.cfm
0912.cfm
some123.cfm
cfm
list.cfm
```

The first loop cycles through our directory contents. The 2nd loop cycles through the number array entries we have inside the cfm file we're looking at. The first if block looks at the current array location contents and compares it to the outer loops name value. The 2nd if looks at the current array location value and the max array location value possible. We know if we reached a current locaction == max location possible - the outer loop element (the directory list) wasn't found in the inner loop (the file array). This is do to the `<cfbreak>` in the first if block. This `<cfbreak>` will break out of the 2nd inner loop when we find a valid match. This prevents the 2nd if block from ever executing on a vaild find.

Hope this helps. Don't forget to accept an answer if you feel it's answered XD

Comment: Thank you.  This was very helpful.  Could you explain what does the second <cfif> do?  Why do we have to check if "i" equals to the elements of fileResult?  How can "i" not equal to fileResult?  Although, this <cfif> tag is needed.

Comment: I added an explanation above. I hope it's not too confusing, I'm not super great at explaining code :P